# Can we programatically change android:icon associated with activity tag in the manifest?

Tags: android

How to programmatically change android:icon associated with an activity tag in android manifest

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the manifest or the resource in the signed-and-sealed APK, except through a software upgrade.

Also, According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) the default's app icon is set in the manifest. As manifest is located in the app's root directory it cannot be modified, so there's no way to do it. You may consider that if you could change it while the app is running, changes wouldn't be saved in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

While the icon is a compile time setting you can change the app icon using an Activity Alias.

```
<activity-alias
    android:name=".MainActivity-IconA"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_a"
    android:label="@string/icon_a_label"
    android:exported="true"
    android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

So you could have multiple of Alias' with different icons. You then just enable/disable each one at run time:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

// Disable Icon A
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    new ComponentName(this, "com.example.MainActivity-IconA"),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
);

// Enable Icon B
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    new ComponentName(this, "com.example.MainActivity-IconB"),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
);
```

This of course means that you know what your icons are going to be a build time too, but at least you can switch between them.

Comment: But, my use case requires icons which will be pushed down from server at runtime. So, build time fix can't help with my usecase

Comment: You can't set `app:icon` at runtime unfortunately. Something that is similar an _may_ help is the widget API: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets  You might be able to create an icon looking widget, but that's a bit of a hack and could be unstable.